# Define macro to log error with file and line in android

Tags: android, c++, logging, java-native-interface, c-preprocessor

I want to make a Error Log that throw in what file and line the problem is using . But I didn't find a good reference. All code is using JNI, C++ side.

This Try fail:

```
#define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR  , LOG_TAG,"%s %s %s",__VA_ARGS__, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

This one only show the msg, no the file and line

```
#define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR  , LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

How could I print all the info clearly? 
Is possible to print only some arguments from `__VA_ARGS__`, something like `__VA_NARG__` ?
Extra info or useful references for this kind of things?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Very interesting and useful question! I found this solution, which may not be the simplest, but works for me:

```
#define LOGE(x...) do { \
  char buf[512]; \
  sprintf(buf, x); \
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,"TAG", "%s | %s:%i", buf, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
} while (0)
```

This line:

```
LOGE("Test: %i", 42)
```

logs the following:

```
TAG    Test: 42 | path/to/file.cpp:line
```

Beware of the arbitrary `512` length of the buffer if you intend to log longer things!

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can use `snprintf()` to ensure that you don't accidentally exceed the size of your 512-byte buffer.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it but went for the simplest solution, assuming that most logs aren't very long. But that's great to mention `snprintf` too!

Answer (score 2):

This is ancient, but I came across it when searching for the same thing. However, I managed to put together a better solution from multiple sources.

```
#define LOGV(fmt, ...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "Your Tag", "%s: " fmt, __FUNCTION__, ## __VA_ARGS__))
```

You should note that `## __VA_ARGS__` is not standard though. Works on GCC and clang though, so no issues with Android.

Answer (score 1):

I settled on this:

```
#define TP_STR_HELPER(x) #x
#define TP_STR(x) TP_STR_HELPER(x)

#define DLog(fmt, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "BLAH", "%s:%s " fmt "\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, TP_STR(__LINE__), ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this (modifying it according to your needs):

```
#include <android/log.h>
#define LOGD(tag, fmt, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, tag, fmt "\n--> %s\n----> %s:%d", ##__VA_ARGS__, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__)
#define LOGE(tag, fmt, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, tag, fmt "\n--> %s\n----> %s:%d", ##__VA_ARGS__, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__)
```

and in code it can be used like this:

```
LOGD("TAG", "debug message");
LOGE("TAG", "error message");
std::string msg = "dynamic message";
LOGD("TAG", "%s", msg.c_str());
```